# Obtaining the size of a UIModalPresentationFormSheet at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I'm making an app for the iPad, it's mainly a `UISplitViewController` app with a settings button which opens up a settings view controller using a `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` as below:

```
SettingsViewController * settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
settingsViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

UINavigationController * settingsNC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsViewController];
settingsNC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
settingsNC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:settingsNC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Within `viewDidLoad` of the `settingsViewController` I want to be able to get the width and height of the popover, how can I do this? I have tried to use the following but they both return the whole iPad screen dimensions..

```
NSLog(@"x: %f y: %f ",self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height);
NSLog(@"x: %f y: %f ",self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);

// outputs 
// x: 1024.000000 y: 748.000000 
// x: 1024.000000 y: 748.000000
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try your NSLog code in `viewWillAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad`. You may need to do `self.navigationController.view.frame.size` to take into account the nav bar height.

Comment: viewWillAppear is not being called, I believe this is because it's within a UINavigationController..

Comment: If you are seeing your settings controller appear on screen then `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` should be getting called. Might be worth you posting more code.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcKinnel That worked, it needed to be in viewWillAppear to work. Would this be because the view hadn't technically been set up as the current view when I was trying to get the values? Thanks.

Comment: And `viewWillAppear` was being called - I just forgot the `:(BOOL)animated`...!

Comment: viewDidLoad only deals with view loading. layout happens afterwards which is when the frames all get adjusted.

Comment: Makes a lot more sense, and it has helped me out with a few other issues I was having with repositioning elements when the keyboard is displayed and hidden!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Rory I have got this working correctly, the calls to find out the size of the view controller just need to be done within the viewWillAppear method. When called within viewDidLoad it returns the bounds of the superview instead, which is why it was returning the whole screen dimensions - I would assume this is due to the presented view controller not technically being active until after viewDidLoad.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"x: %f y: %f ",self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height);
    NSLog(@"x: %f y: %f ",self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
}

// outputs
// x: 540.000000 y: 576.000000 
// x: 540.000000 y: 576.000000
```